# C# RESTful POST with image and body

Tags: c#, rest, post, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I am currently trying to POST some data to server to create user profile. The body of RESTful POST has selected image and also other fields.

I managed to POST it using Postman. However, I am trying to figure out how to do it using C#. I attempted but it seems that server returns status 500 without much useful message.

Please refer attachments on how i POST to server and some C# code on how I attempted to POST it. Appreciate help on how to fix my C# code to make it work.

[image]
[image]

C# code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
        {
            var fullUrl = baseUrl + "/user_profiles";
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", apiKey);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
                var boundary = "Upload----" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.Name) ? "" : userRegistration.Name;
                        var city = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.City) ? "" : userRegistration.City.ToUpper();
                        var phone = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.Mobile) ? "" : userRegistration.Mobile;
                        phone = phone.Replace(" ", ""); //remove empty string in between and at edges
                        phone = phone.StartsWith("+") ? phone : "+" + phone;
                        var address = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.CompanyAddress) ? "Unspecified" : userRegistration.CompanyAddress;
                        var country = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.Country) ? "" : userRegistration.Country.ToUpper();
                        var email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.Email) ? "" : userRegistration.Email;
                        var isContractor = userRegistration.IsRegisteredAsContractor.ToString();
                        var category = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.Category) ? "" : userRegistration.Category;
                        var companyName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.CompanyName) ? "" : userRegistration.CompanyName;
                        var companyAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.CompanyAddress) ? "" : userRegistration.CompanyAddress;

                        //TEST
                        //var body = new
                        //{
                        //    city,
                        //    phone,
                        //    address,
                        //    country,
                        //    email,
                        //    name,
                        //    identifier_for_vendor = localId,
                        //    is_contractor = isContractor,
                        //    work_categories = category,
                        //    company_name = companyName,
                        //    company_address = companyAddress
                        //};

                        //var bodyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                        //var stringContent = new StringContent(bodyStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        //content.Add(stringContent);
                        //response = await httpClient.PostAsync(fullUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        //TEST

                        content.Add(new StringContent(name, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "name");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(city, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "city");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(phone, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "phone");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(companyAddress, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "address");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(country, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "country");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(email, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "email");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(localId, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "identifier_for_vendor");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(isContractor, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "is_contractor");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(category, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "work_categories");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(companyName, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "company_name");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(companyAddress, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), "company_address");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRegistration.ProfileImagePath) && File.Exists(userRegistration.ProfileImagePath))
                        {
                            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(userRegistration.ProfileImagePath))
                            {
                                //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
                                content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "image", fileName);
                                response = await httpClient.PostAsync(fullUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(fullUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `File.OpenRead`, It will return a File Stream (Bytes)
You need to convert it to Base64 which is the preferred way of sending images over REST.

```
base64Image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(stream);
```

After that, you will need to convert it back on your backend and store it where ever you want.

Also, I wouldn't recommend using FormDataContent to send the data since it has some size limitations.

I recommend using `JObject`and adding what you want to send as `JProperty`.

```
Uri postURL = new Uri(Constants.RestUrl + "/NewReservation");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
client.Timeout = timeout;                   

var UserData = AccountCheck.CurrentUserData();

JObject RequestData = new JObject(
    new JProperty("apiKey", UserData.ApiKey),
    new JProperty("customerID", UserData.CustomerId.ToString()),
    new JProperty("containerIDs", NewReservationRequest.ContainerIDs),
    new JProperty("containersQuantities", NewReservationRequest.ContainerQuantities),
    new JProperty("location", NewReservationRequest.Location),
    new JProperty("image", NewReservationRequest.ImageBlob),
    new JProperty("dateFrom", NewReservationRequest.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
    new JProperty("dateTo", NewReservationRequest.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
    new JProperty("expectedTime",NewReservationRequest.ExpectedTime),
    new JProperty("remarks", UserRemarks)
                );


var RequestDataString = new StringContent(RequestData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage responsePost = await client.PostAsync(postURL, RequestDataString);
string response = await responsePost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

After that , you will need to parse the json response. 
reply to this answer if you need more help

Comment: Can you provide a simple example on your recommendation using FormDataContent? My goal is to POST a body that has both image binary and also the require fields to the server (please refer to the Postman screenshots).

Comment: You will need something like this website to convert an image to base64 and put it as a json in FormData
https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter

Comment: FormData is simple to use in postman but I got some exceptions when sending big images in C#

Comment: Thanks for the code example. So based on your example, the value for "NewReservationRequest.ImageBlob" is basically a converted version of image stream ie byte array? Or is it the ".ToString()" of the byte array?

Comment: It's the base64String as the start of the answer 
base64Image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(stream);

Comment: You can test with postman if you do var RequestString = RequestData.ToString(); and copy that to Postman

Comment: Format the Json online to make it readable. There are many websites that does that such as https://jsonlint.com

Comment: I tried the method you suggested. I got a 5xx error from the server. Not sure why though...

Comment: If you got 5xx error, that usually means that the error on your server side and not frontend code. You need to debug and share the format of what you are sending and what are you getting.